# Why don't all my checkboxes have the same behavior?

Tags: javascript, dom, checkbox

I'm adding some interactivity to a form.

A user will select from a range of activities. Some of the activities have a time-clash.

If a user selects one of the activities with a time-clash, then the activity it clashes with will be disabled and unable to be selected.

If the user then DEselects that checkbox, then they are all enabled and are free to choose any checkbox they want.

Right now, I can disable all the correct boxes. But I am unable to disable them again, aside from the first, frameworks. With the others, I am locked with my decision and have to refresh the page. Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

> Javascript

```
// Register for Activities section of the form.
document.querySelector(".activities").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var main = document.getElementById("all");
  var framework = document.getElementById("framework");
  var libs = document.getElementById("libs");
  var express = document.getElementById("express");
  var node = document.getElementById("node");
  var build = document.getElementById("build");
  var npm = document.getElementById("npm");
  var frameworkLbl = document.getElementById("frameworkLabel");
  var libsLbl = document.getElementById("libsLabel");
  var expressLbl = document.getElementById("expressLabel");
  var nodeLbl = document.getElementById("nodeLabel");

  // If the user selects a workshop, don't allow selection of a workshop at the same date and time -- you should disable the checkbox and visually indicate that the workshop in the competing time slot isn't available.
  if(framework.checked == true) {
    express.disabled = true;
    expressLbl.style.color = "grey";
  } else if(express.checked == true) {
    framework.disabled = true;
    frameworkLbl.style.color = "grey";
  } else if(libs.checked == true) {
    node.disabled = true;
    nodeLbl.style.color = "grey";
  } else if(node.checked == true) {
    libs.disabled = true;
    libsLbl.style.color = "grey";
  }

  // When a user unchecks an activity, make sure that competing activities (if there are any) are no longer disabled.
  if(framework.checked == false) {
    express.disabled = false;
    expressLbl.style.color = "black";
  } else if(express.checked == false) {
    framework.disabled = false;
    frameworkLbl.style.color = "black";
  } else if(libs.checked == false) {
    node.disabled = false;
    nodeLbl.style.color = "black";
  } else if(node.checked == false) {
    libs.disabled = false;
    libsLbl.style.color = "black";
  }
});
```

> HTML

```
<fieldset class="activities">
  <legend>Register for Activities</legend>
  <div id="activityReminder"></div>
  <div id="lineBreak"></div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" class="activity"> Main Conference — $200</label>
  <label id="frameworkLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks" id="framework" class="activity"> JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
  <label id="libsLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="js-libs" id="libs" class="activity"> JavaScript Libraries Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
  <label id="expressLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="express" id="express" class="activity"> Express Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
  <label id="nodeLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="node" id="node" class="activity"> Node.js Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>          
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="build-tools" id="build" class="activity"> Build tools Workshop — Wednesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="npm" id="npm" class="activity"> npm Workshop — Wednesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your checkbox and dependent checkbox group are supposed to be independent of other checkbox groups.

The implication of your else if statements is that you have made all of them dependent on each other. They are supposed to be separate if statements.

So, a working correction is

```
// Register for Activities section of the form.
document.querySelector(".activities").addEventListener("change", function(){
    var main = document.getElementById("all");
    var framework = document.getElementById("framework");
    var libs = document.getElementById("libs");
    var express = document.getElementById("express");
    var node = document.getElementById("node");
    var build = document.getElementById("build");
    var npm = document.getElementById("npm");

    var frameworkLbl = document.getElementById("frameworkLabel");
    var libsLbl = document.getElementById("libsLabel");
    var expressLbl = document.getElementById("expressLabel");
    var nodeLbl = document.getElementById("nodeLabel");


    // If the user selects a workshop, don't allow selection of a workshop at the same date and time -- you should disable the checkbox and visually indicate that the workshop in the competing time slot isn't available.
    if(framework.checked == true) {
        express.disabled = true;
        expressLbl.style.color = "grey";
    }
    if(express.checked == true) {
        framework.disabled=  true;
        frameworkLbl.style.color = "grey";
    }
    if(libs.checked == true) {
        node.disabled = true;
        nodeLbl.style.color = "grey";
    }
    if(node.checked == true) {
        libs.disabled = true;
        libsLbl.style.color = "grey";
    } 

    // When a user unchecks an activity, make sure that competing activities (if there are any) are no longer disabled.
    if(framework.checked == false) {
        express.disabled = false;
        expressLbl.style.color = "black";
    }
    if(express.checked == false) {
        framework.disabled = false;
        frameworkLbl.style.color = "black";
    }
    if(libs.checked == false) {
        node.disabled = false;
        nodeLbl.style.color = "black";
    }
    if(node.checked == false) {
        libs.disabled = false;
        libsLbl.style.color = "black";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `if else`'s to `if`'s. They are being overlooked as they're chained to `if(framework.checked == false)` and `if(framework.checked == true)`

Comment: aaah.. dfasoro beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

## Syntax Error

In some browsers `elem.disabled` not working, so:
To **disable** checkbox in `HTML` you only have to add the `disabled` attribute, and to enable it again you must remove the `disabled` attribute and **NOT** to assign `false`

## Solution

```js
// Register for Activities section of the form.
document.querySelector(".activities").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var main = document.getElementById("all");
  var framework = document.getElementById("framework");
  var libs = document.getElementById("libs");
  var express = document.getElementById("express");
  var node = document.getElementById("node");
  var build = document.getElementById("build");
  var npm = document.getElementById("npm");
  var frameworkLbl = document.getElementById("frameworkLabel");
  var libsLbl = document.getElementById("libsLabel");
  var expressLbl = document.getElementById("expressLabel");
  var nodeLbl = document.getElementById("nodeLabel");

  // If the user selects a workshop, don't allow selection of a workshop at the same date and time -- you should disable the checkbox and visually indicate that the workshop in the competing time slot isn't available.
  if(framework.checked == true) {
    //express.disabled = true;
    disableElement(express);
    expressLbl.style.color = "grey";
  } else if(express.checked == true) {
    //framework.disabled = true;
    disableElement(framework);
    frameworkLbl.style.color = "grey";
  } else if(libs.checked == true) {
    //node.disabled = true;
    disableElement(node);
    nodeLbl.style.color = "grey";
  } else if(node.checked == true) {
    //libs.disabled = true;
    disableElement(libs);
    libsLbl.style.color = "grey";
  }

  // When a user unchecks an activity, make sure that competing activities (if there are any) are no longer disabled.
  if(framework.checked == false) {
    //express.disabled = false;
    enableElement(express);
    expressLbl.style.color = "black";
  }
//  else
  if(express.checked == false) {
    //framework.disabled = false;
    enableElement(framework);
    frameworkLbl.style.color = "black";
  } 
//  else
  if(libs.checked == false) {
    //node.disabled = false;
    enableElement(node);
    nodeLbl.style.color = "black";
  }
//  else 
  if(node.checked == false) {
    //libs.disabled = false;
    enableElement(libs);
    libsLbl.style.color = "black";
  }
  console.log("express.checked=" +(express.checked));
});

function disableElement(elem){
  var att = document.createAttribute("disabled");       // Create a "disabled" attribute
  elem.setAttributeNode(att);
}

function enableElement(elem){
  elem.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="activities">
  <legend>Register for Activities</legend>
  <div id="activityReminder"></div>
  <div id="lineBreak"></div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="all" id="all" class="activity"> Main Conference — $200</label>
  <label id="frameworkLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks" id="framework" class="activity"> JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
  <label id="libsLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="js-libs" id="libs" class="activity"> JavaScript Libraries Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
  <label id="expressLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="express" id="express" class="activity"> Express Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
  <label id="nodeLabel"><input type="checkbox" name="node" id="node" class="activity"> Node.js Workshop — Tuesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>          
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="build-tools" id="build" class="activity"> Build tools Workshop — Wednesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="npm" id="npm" class="activity"> npm Workshop — Wednesday 1pm-4pm, $100</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's significant opportunity to DRY your code up.  [For example](https://jsfiddle.net/camerican/keoq6f1x/), if you use an array to track competing timeslots, you can avoid the verbose use of variables and logic blocks by relying upon your naming conventions:

```
var timeslots = [['framework','express'],['libs','node'],['build'],['npm']];

document.querySelector(".activities").addEventListener("change", function(e){
    timeslots.filter(function(slot){
      return slot.indexOf(e.target.id) > -1;
    })[0].forEach(function(lecture){
      var checkbox = document.getElementById(lecture);
      var label = document.getElementById(lecture+'Label');
      // deactivate competing
      if( e.target.checked == true ) {
        if( lecture != e.target.id ) {
           checkbox.disabled = true;
           label.style.color = 'grey';
        }
      } else { //reactivate competing
        if( lecture != e.target.id ) {
           checkbox.disabled = false;
           label.style.color = 'black';
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Here we use `Array#filter` to find the timeslot our changed checkbox lives within.  We're able to do so by using the `event.target` that we are capturing via the anonymous callback passed to the `change` listener (we're calling the local variable `e` here, by convention).

Presuming that a lecture exists in only one timeslot, we get the first position returned by filter and loop over each inner array with `Array#forEach`.  We then activate or deactivate all competing checkboxes and labels using your naming convention.  This will make your JavaScript code more maintainable, by simply modifying the *timeslots* array should your HTML form ever require updating.